# How does a Rails controller get access to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

In the [Rails guide tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), the `articles` controller magically gets access to the `Article` model. Is this done for you automatically as long the controller and model name matches? Or do **all** controllers have access to any model of their choosing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not magical, and this is not limited to controllers and models, Rails (depending on the version you are using) autoloads every class and module under the `app/` directory, meaning you have access to any class from any other class in the whole project. So if you add a new directory and file under the `app/` directory, like `app/services/foo_bar.rb`. You can also access that from your controller, or your model, or from another service class, eg:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @article = Article.new
    FooBar.do_something(@article)
  end
end
```

or:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  #....

  private

  def lets_all_foo_our_bars
    FooBar.foo_my_bar
  end
end
```

Comment: This is also very useful guide to refer https://gist.github.com/maxim/6503591